# Dynamic combo collection_select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, combobox

I am using two collection_select

**Views**

```
<%= collection_select(@table, "gm", @strs, "country", "country", {:prompt => "Select Country"}) %>
<%= submit_tag value="Proceed-->"%> 

<%= collection_select(@table, "sp", @pops, "state", "state", {:prompt => "Select State"}) %>
<%= submit_tag value="Submit"%>
```

**Controller**

```
@strs = Table.find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT country FROM tables ORDER BY country")

@pops = Table.find(:all, :conditions=>{:country => params[:gm]}, :order=> 'state', :select=> 'DISTINCT state')
```

Here, these are relational collection_select. I need to populate the second collection_select once first collection_select was selected. Now I am using submit key. But, once "Proceed" submit was processed, params[gm] was disabled. So I am unable to process "Submit" tag with both params[gm] and params[sp] for @table.

I found some idea to create dynamic collection_select using javascript. But, I need to populate dynamically or single time processing of relational params[gm] and params[sp] using rails alone. please anyone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is what you're looking for
[Country-State Select Using Carmen and jQuery](http://eric.lubow.org/2009/ruby/rails/country-state-select-using-carmen-and-jquery/)

Comment: Hoa: Yaa... Exactly as mentioned.. but, I need to apply this concept without javascripts. Any idea with Rails?

Comment: Even if you want to implement the feature on the server side, some JavaScript is required. To be specific, when a user selects a country, you have to submit the form to obtain the corresponding states. And the form submission here will be triggered by JavaScript onchange event.